# Angular watch cycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'd like to create a color picker based on [farbtastic color picker](http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/). What I'm trying to achieve is adding RGB sliders that I want to link to the color wheel. Here's what I have so far.

```
app.controller('PickAColorController', function ($scope) {
$('#colorpicker').farbtastic(function (col) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.color.setColor(col);
    });
});

$scope.$watch('color.r', function () {
    var color = chroma($scope.color.r, $scope.color.g, $scope.color.b);
    var cp = $.farbtastic('#colorpicker');
    cp.setColor(color.hex());
})

$scope.color = {
    hex:'',
    r: 0,
    g: 0,
    b: 0,
    
    setColor: function (hexCode) {
        this.hex = hexCode;
        var rgb = chroma(hexCode).rgb(); 
        this.r = rgb[0];
        this.g = rgb[1];
        this.b = rgb[2];
    }
};
});
```

It works fine without the watch but with it I get

```
 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
 at Error (native)
 ...
```

which, I suspect, is due to my modification to the color that triggers another change to my watched variable and so on... leading to a cycle and if I'm not mistaken after a couple of runs angular terminates this and throws an error. So can you suggest a clean way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use `$timeout` which will call $apply internally but will be pushed to end of digest queue and thus avoid the `in progress` error.

```
$('#colorpicker').farbtastic(function (col) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.color.setColor(col);
    });
});
```

Don't forget to inject `$timeout` in controller.

Note- DOM manipulation code like this doesn't belong in controller and should always be placed in directives

Comment: Could you outline how you would go about that?

Comment: not hard to find in web search like `angular jQuery plugin directive` or similar. Basics are really pretty simple...advantage also that code won;t run until element actually exists